# Mongodb: Get all documents before ChangeStream started

Tags: c#, mongodb

**I don't know how to mark this question as answered, but its already answered by @Neil Lunn**

I am using C# to get the ChangeStream.

Currently, Mongodb change stream behaves so that it starts monitoring for changes from time it has started. But if the change stream is started after some documents already inserted, then I do not see those documents which where previously stored.

So, the question is. Is it possible I can configure the ChangeStream so that it gives me all the documents which I have not seen yet.

I know there is something called ResumeToken but it takes a token of the Changed item.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Are you expecting to see every change ever made before the stream/watch was invoked? In reality if your application wants to track these things then you should open the stream before you write anything. The resumetoken thing is there so you can persist "last seen" in other storage and use that on subsequent application restarts.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I wanted to get all changes from the time database created til the time I have started the changestream and then beyond that.

Comment: Thought so. That's not how it works.Read the documentation around the part where it even mentions ["Resuming"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#resume-a-change-stream). The whole thing is based on the [Oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/), and data in that only sticks around for a *very limited* period of time.

Comment: Alright, yes I read about that. i just wanted to confirm that is the case and there none that i dont know. ok thanks for the clarification